# Get f95 to work in Cygwin environment (Windows 10)

Tags: makefile, fortran, cygwin, gfortran

I am trying to compile a [program](https://github.com/usgs/landslides-trigrs) using Cygwin Toolbox. I am running into the following error when I run `make`:

```
make: f95: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:32: trg] Error 127
```

I looked through the available Cygwin packages but did not find f95 as one of them. I thought gfortran would take care of that. How do I get f95 to work smoothly with Cygwin?

Comment: At my system (Windows 7, 32 bit Cygwin) f95 is a symbolic link `f95 -> gfortran.exe` in `/usr/bin` maybe a workaround is to create the symbolic link yourself  (at least when gfortran, which version ?, is installed properly. Did the Cygwin installation of gfortran complete without errors?

Comment: The Cygwin install was perfectly fine. The gfortran version is 8.2.0. I like the idea of creating a symbolic link. How do you do that? Also would it fix the problem of running makefiles which use f95?

Comment: My version is 7.3.0 so can be something in the 8.2.0 version. For the symbolic link have a look at the man page of the `ln` command so on the `/usr/bon` direcory `ln -s gfortran.exe f95` though I think the saver way would be to define your Forran compiler as gfortran or change the Makefile.

Comment: My fortran compiler *is* gfortran. Doing a `which gfortran` reveals that it is located in my mingw installation /bin folder. However when I check in there I don't see any f95, only gfortran. Also I definitely do not want to be changing the Makefile. This is coming from a public repository and I want to adapt my machine to running the code as it is. Not the other way round.

Comment: Well than you have to create the symbolic link on the `/bin` directory. Maybe the command f95 is not supported anymore with gfortran 8.2.0 (check release notes)

Comment: I don't really see anything on removing support for f95 in the release notes: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/ Also this link https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1598231 seems to indicate that the symbolic link should already be defined out of the box

Comment: No idea why the link is not present in your case (was just a wild guess regarding the remove).